# Having trouble understanding sarl in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am having trouble understanding a loop in an IsPrime function. I mainly have trouble understand the first couple of lines in the code. x86 assembly 32 bit. The stack is size 36. There is a possibility that there is an error in the code

```
.L4:        #odd number
movl    8(%ebp), %eax               #move arg(odd number) into eax
movl    %eax, -28(%ebp)             
movl    $1431655766, -32(%ebp)      #having trouble understanding this line
movl    -32(%ebp), %edx
imull   -28(%ebp)                                     
movl    %edx, %ecx
movl    -28(%ebp), %eax
sarl    $31, %edx                   #and what this does
movl    %ecx, %edx
subl    %eax, %edx
movl    %edx, -24(%ebp)
movl    -24(%ebp), %eax
addl    %eax, %eax
addl    -24(%ebp), %eax
movl    -28(%ebp), %ecx
subl    %eax, %ecx
movl    %ecx, -24(%ebp)
cmpl    $0, -24(%ebp)
jne .L7
cmpl    $3, 8(%ebp)
jne .L6
```

Comment: If it's a homework and "A. Bhattacharjee" is your teacher, then brother, you are in trouble !

Answer (score 0):

I would advise compiling with optimizations. Unoptimized code contains a lot of superfluous stores to the stack, obscuring the important instructions. **Don't add to the haystack.**
 Now let's look at the program:

```
.L4:        #odd number
movl    8(%ebp), %eax            #move arg to eax register, which is an implicit
                                 #operand of multiplication operations
movl    %eax, -28(%ebp)          #store arg to a local variable
movl    $1431655766, -32(%ebp)   #store an immediate value to a local variable
                                 #not terribly useful but OK
movl    -32(%ebp), %edx          #move local variable into edx before imul???
                                 #completely useless.
imull   -28(%ebp)                #imull calculates 64bit result of eax*local_var
                                 #which is the same as eax, so eax*eax
                                 #and stores the result in edx:eax, so the
                                 #previous write to edx is
                                 #unconditionally overwritten
movl    %edx, %ecx               #store high 32bits of the mul to ecx, OK
movl    -28(%ebp), %eax          #reload eax from stack var, OK
sarl    $31, %edx                #shift right by 31 arithmetically
                                 #(~divide by 2 to the power of 31,
                                 #preserving and extending the sign bit)
                                 #also useless due to the next instruction:
movl    %ecx, %edx               #move ecx to edx.
subl    %eax, %edx 
movl    %edx, -24(%ebp) 
movl    -24(%ebp), %eax
addl    %eax, %eax
addl    -24(%ebp), %eax
movl    -28(%ebp), %ecx
subl    %eax, %ecx
movl    %ecx, -24(%ebp)
cmpl    $0, -24(%ebp)
jne .L7
cmpl    $3, 8(%ebp)
jne .L6
```

As you see, the instructions you were wondering about are completely useless, as their side effects are immediately overwritten by other instructions before they are used.
In fact, this is so egregious I have to wonder where this code came from.
It could either be produced by a truly atrocious compiler, or it is hand written garbage.
Again, use a good compiler and enable optimizations, the code will be much more sensible.